# About the release price

Tags: ros, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dears:
If I want to developed a sensor driver and release up to ROS. Needs to charged any price from ROS?

best regards,
Emma

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249862/about-the-release-price./) by [EmmaHsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28781/emmahsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No! ROS is open source (http://www.ros.org/is-ros-for-me/) and if you want to release something as open source as well, you are free to do so.
Check out the [bloom documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom) which is the release toolchain used in ROS.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EmmaHsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28781/emmahsu/) on 2016-12-12**:
Thanks for your reply :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-12**:
Perhaps 'open-source' could use some clarification: [wikipedia/zh/open-source](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BC%80%E6%94%BE%E6%BA%90%E4%BB%A3%E7%A0%81).

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-12-12**:
And "open source" -> "commercially usable" is not a valid conclusion!!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-12**:
@NEngelhard: could you clarify that statement a bit? Are you referring to licensing or code quality (or both)?

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-12-12**:
I was referring to the license. Just being open source is not enough for being commercially usable.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-12-12**:
@NEngelhard @gvdhoorn  good points. But I understood the questions as: "do I have to pay to release a package".

This is a clean "No, you don't have to." Whether the release package is suitable for anything is another matter ;-)